# What verb describes the action of bringing an error into being?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a technical document that uses *checked run-time error* and *unchecked run-time error* as terms of art.  I need to talk about what happens when a computer program does something bad and causes one of these errors, but I'm not sure what verb to use.

- In English, we *make* a "mistake," but I'm pretty sure we don't "make" an error.
- Do we *commit* an error?
- Do we *cause* an error?

Ideas appreciated.  Sources, example usage, and authorities even more appreciated.

Sample phrase:

> If client code *verbs* an unchecked run-time error, the
>   implementation provides no guarantees; anything can happen.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32423/discussion-on-question-by-norman-ramsey-what-verb-describes-the-action-of-bringi).

Comment: The error was *injected* due to erroneous coding or hardware design, and it was *detected* or *sensed* when runtime checks in hardware or software, uh, detected or sensed it.  It is *latent* if it has not been detected.

Comment: But note that an *unchecked* runtime error is one that occurs without being detected.  This causes the error to *propagate* into later stages of processing where it's effects may be detected, or may be ignored entirely, causing the error to, eg, cause a check for $1,234,567 dollars to be mailed, vs the correct amount of $1.23.  But the terminology around this can get pretty detailed, and you really need to find a good tutorial on the terms and concepts involved.

Comment: But in the specific case of the above sample phrase, "causes" would be the appropriate verb.

Comment: Note that, in the sample phrase, the client code presumably already contained a (previously "injected") programming error which in turn caused the "unchecked runtime error".  "Unchecked" in this case means that an erroneous operation occurred (say, data was garbled) but no error was detected by the system (ie, no exception was raised, no error was logged, etc).

Comment: In this context, I always use the verb **trigger**: *Client code triggers an unchecked run-time error*.

Comment: Thanks KitZ.Fox.  Why are people so much more eager to write comments than to write answers?  Answers can be upvoted!  @Graffito I'm looking at you...

Comment: @NormanRamsey - Sometimes, we haven't the courage to write answers with supporting text or arguments :(

Comment: @NormanRamsey The comments can be upvoted, too. But they can not be downvoted. And there are [insert favorite expletive] out there who don't bother to explain with a comment why an answer is wrong, simply downvoting and moving on. I have seen it several times on different answers from other users which I have found useful, or neutral. It once happened with my answer, too. From that time on, I also prefer commenting to answering.

Comment: In English (that is, not, unfortunately, in computer jargon) we *err*, unless we're divine, then we *forgive* (the unfortunate use of jargon when plain English will do).

Comment: Don't we *fall into error*?

Comment: I can't migrate comments twice, which means if you don't use the chat room, I'll have to just delete these comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an error seems to be far more broadly used than *cause an error* and *commit an error* as the below Ngram Viewer shows:

[image]

However, if you search "code makes an error", "code causes an error" and "code commits error", only ***code causes an error*** appears. I would advise you to use ***cause*** before ***an unchecked run-time error***.

[image]

Comment: @HotLicks Can you elaborate on your comment? I am at a loss.

Comment: The Ngram Viewer looks like a really nice tool; I wasn't aware of it.  Big crossover between "commit" and "cause" from 19th to 20th centuries.  And "trigger and error" comes on only since 1990.  Very interesting; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Personally I think I might use any of *make*, *commit*, or *cause* depending on what I was talking about.**

I think my likely choice would be in that order, i.e. make, commit, cause.

If the error was due to something I'd done that was of an everyday nature, such as written an address wrongly, I think I would say *Oh dear, it looks as if I've made an error*.

If it was something very big and important it might be *commit*. E.g. *A large minority of people in Britain believe the House of Commons is committing a major error in agreeing to authorise the Government's extension of its bombing campaign to Syria, as well as Iraq*

If it was a discussion about how an error had occurred, of if it involved a system or procedure of some kind I think I would say *The error appears to have been caused by a programming fault* or *There will now be a big argument as to who was responsible for causing the error*.

Comment: Basically I agree with WS2. However I have a comment concerning the word "error". I think an "error" is something that happens, whereas a "mistake" is something that is committed by somebody. So "make a mistake" is correct, but "commit a mistake" is more lofty style, which I would prefer.

Comment: Keep in mind that "commit" has a specific meaning in computer science.

Comment: When an error "happens" to stop a hardware peripheral from working, like for instance a paper jam in a printer, the device may send a signal that it has a problem.  It could make a red light turn on, meaning "I need help from a human!"  That's what I associate with the language "raise an error".  That's not a mistake -- these things happen.

Answer (score 1):

Java, .NET, and probably other modern languages use the terms (which are also keywords) **throw** and **catch** to describe error handling.  If your code generates an unintentional error, then it is said to 'throw' an error, also known as 'exception', and there may or may not be exception handling logic that 'catches' the exception.  When you 'catch' the exception, your code may take some type of action such as logging it, and then possibly 're-throw' the exception back to the calling code so it knows something's wrong.

Here's probably more info than you ever needed to know https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx on this

Comment: Thanks, but by its very nature, an **_unchecked run-time error_** is neither detected nor handled.

Comment: Right.  So in your example, I would just say "If client code throws an unchecked run-time error, the implementation provides no guarantees; anything can happen.

Comment: There is no throwing action here.  An unchecked run-time error is silently undetected.

Comment: To err is human.  To throw an exception takes a third generation programming language.